# Cleaning old snapshots from hosted snapshots repository in nexus 3.4

Tags: java, nexus

I am trying to get rid of a huge amount of old snapshots in our nexus repository. First try was to setup a `Remove snapshots from Maven repository` task in nexus to keep one snapshot and purge things older than 30 days. But from the logs:

```
RemoveSnapshotsTask - Executing removal of snapshots on repository: RepositoryImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$afd74251{type=hosted, format=maven2, name='snapshots'}
RemoveSnapshotsFacetImpl - Removing snapshots on repository snapshots with configuration: org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.tasks.RemoveSnapshotsConfig(1, 30, true, 14)
RemoveSnapshotsFacetImpl - Processing 5541 GAVs found with more than minimum 1 snapshot versions
RemoveSnapshotsFacetImpl - Finished processing snapshots with more than 1 versions created before 2017-06-20T06:43:02.135Z
RemoveSnapshotsFacetImpl - Deleted 0 components from 0 distinct GAVs
RemoveSnapshotsFacetImpl - Processing 0 GAVs found that have already been released and for which the grace period has elapsed
RemoveSnapshotsFacetImpl - Finished processing snapshots with associated releases
RemoveSnapshotsFacetImpl - Updating metadata on repository: snapshots
```

That did not remove a single snapshot at all. But there are many snapshots 17.5.106-20161103.155102-1 to 17.5.251-20170718.203928-1 and most of them older than 30 days.

How to get rid of those?

Of course I could delete the repository and recreate it from time to time - but automated cleanups would be much nicer.

Comment: It may just be a typo but in your example: "17.5.106-20161103.155102-1 to 251-20170718.203928-1" are not the same GAV (one is version 17.5.106 the other version 251) so these would not be removed by the snapshot remover.  For the remover to work you'd need distinct versions OR to set your minimum count lower than 1 (to 0, this should remove both in the example).  If you're unsure, I suggest making a backup of your instance and blobstore first.  However you sound like you're willing to delete repo, may not care much.  If this ends up being the answer for you, let me know, I can make an answer.

Comment: @joedragons that was a typo indeed - it should have been 17.5.106-20161103.155102-1 to 17.5.251-20170718.203928-1 - what I want is that all GAVs before a certain version 17.5.240 or age as 30 days are evicted from the snapshot repo.

Comment: I don't believe there's a scheduled task to do exactly that.  You could propose something on https://issues.sonatype.org/projects/NEXUS/issues.  Have you considered the "Purge unused Maven snapshot versions" task?  It sounds more like what you want, esp if you're running your task manually.  If automated, you'd have to be careful that you're consistently inputting the latest otherwise, you could remove the last snapshot.

Comment: @joedragons Thanks for that input - I will try out that. Otherwise I found a way via REST to list and delete those GAV (but built in would be nicer).

Comment: NP, for posterity I was also assuming you were on NXRM3...which I now think you might not be.  But in case anyone reads my comments, I was thinking thusly.  Principles should be the same tho.